# angle congruence in inscribed triangle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

In $\triangle ABC$ construct altitudes $AA', BB', CC'$ meeting at point M to form the orthocenter of the triangle. Let O be the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$. Show that $\angle BAA' = \angle OAC$ and $AO \perp B'C'$.

The attempt that I have tried: Extending the altitudes to touch the circle at 3 different points. And also constructing AO and extending it to touch the circle at a point. I attempted to show that arc formed from extending $AA'$ and point B was congruent to the arc formed from extending $AO$ and point $C$. This attempt did not work for me, unless I did something wrong and it actually does work. If someone could please provide guidance for this question I would appreciate it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHrAF.png)

Comment: For the first part, use an unknown, $\theta$ say, for $\angle BAA'$. Then chase the angles, noting that $\angle AOC = 2\angle ABC$ (inscribed angle vs central angle), and that triangle $AOC$ is isosceles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is easy . . .

Let $\theta = \angle BAA'$.

Then, using degree measure,

\begin{align*}
\angle ABA' &= 90 - \theta\\[4pt]
\implies \angle ABC &= 90 - \theta&&\text{[since $\angle ABC = \angle ABA'$]}\\[4pt]
\implies \angle AOC &= 2(90 - \theta)&&\text{[central angle is twice inscribed angle]}\\[4pt]
&= 180 - 2\theta\\[4pt]
\implies \angle OAC &= \theta&&\text{[since triangle AOC is isosceles with apex at $O$]}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Therefore $\angle BAA' = \angle OAC$.

The second part seems harder.

Here's a brute force solution using complex numbers . . .

The goal is to show $OA \perp B_1C_1$.

For each vertex, let the corresponding complex number be denoted by the lower case version of the same letter.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Without loss of generality, we can assume
\begin{align*}
&\;\;{\small{\bullet}}\;\;\text{The circumcenter is $0\;$ (by an appropriate translation).}
\\[4pt]
&\;\;{\small{\bullet}}\;\;\text{The circumradius is $1\;$ (by an appropriate scaling).}
\\[4pt]
&\;\;{\small{\bullet}}\;\;a = 1\;\text{(by an appropriate rotation).}
\end{align*}
$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Two simple facts:$\;$If $z$ is a complex number, then
\begin{align*}
&\;\;{\small{\bullet}}\;\;z\;\text{is real if and only if}\;\bar{z}=z
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\,
\\[4pt]
&\;\;{\small{\bullet}}\;\;z\;\text{is pure imaginary if and only if}\;\bar{z}=-z
\\[12pt]
\end{align*}

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Since $|b|=|c|=1$, we have 
$$
\bar{b}={\small{\frac{1}{b}}}\;\text{and}\;\bar{c}={\small{\frac{1}{c}}}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\,
$$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Since $B_1$ is on line $AC$,

\begin{align*}
b_1 &= 1 + s(c-1),\;\text{for some}\;s \in\mathbb{R}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;
\\[4pt]
\implies\;\overline{b_1} &= 1 + s(\bar{c} - 1)
\\[4pt]
&=1 + s\left({\small{\frac{1}{c}}} - 1\right)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Next, let

$$
p = \frac{b - b_1}{c-1}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;
$$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Then

\begin{align*}
&B_1B \perp AC
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\,
\\[4pt]
\implies\; &p\;\text{is pure imaginary}
\\[4pt]
\implies\; &\bar{p}=-p
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Simplifying $p$, we get
\begin{align*}
p &= \frac{b - b_1}{c-1}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;
\\[4pt]
&= \frac{b- \left(1 + s(c-1)\right)}{c-1}
\\[4pt]
&= \frac{b-1}{c-1} - s
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Then

\begin{align*}
p &= \frac{b-1}{c-1} - s
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
\\[4pt]
\implies\;\bar{p} &= \frac{\bar{b}-1}{\bar{c}-1} - s
\\[4pt]
&= \frac{\frac{1}{b}-1}{\frac{1}{c}-1} - s
\\[4pt]
&= \frac{c(b-1)}{b(c-1)} - s
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Hence

\begin{align*}
&\bar{p}=-p
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;
\\[6pt]
\implies\; &\frac{c(b-1)}{b(c-1)} - s = s - \frac{b-1}{c-1}
\\[4pt]
\implies\; &s = \frac{(b+c)(b-1)}{2b(c-1)}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Then

\begin{align*}
b_1 &= 1 + s(c-1)
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;
\\[4pt]
&= 1 +  \left(\frac{(b+c)(b-1)}{2b(c-1)}\right)(c-1)
\\[4pt]
&= 1 +  \frac{(b+c)(b-1)}{2b}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Thus, we have

$$
b_1 = 1 +  \frac{(b+c)(b-1)}{2b}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;
$$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
By analogous reasoning, we get

$$
c_1 = 1 +  \frac{(b+c)(c-1)}{2c}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;
$$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Then

\begin{align*}
&OA \perp B_1C_1
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;
\\[6pt]
\iff &\frac{c_1-b_1}{a}\;\text{is pure imaginary}
\\[4pt]
\iff\; &c_1-b_1\;\text{is pure imaginary}\qquad\text{[since a = 1]}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
Let $w = c_1-b_1.\,$ It remains to show $\bar{w} = - w.\;$Then

\begin{align*}
w &= c_1-b_1
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\\[4pt]
&= \left(1 +  \frac{(b+c)(c-1)}{2c}\right)-\left(1 +  \frac{(b+c)(b-1)}{2b}\right)
\\[4pt]
&= \frac{c^2-b^2}{2bc}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;
\bar{w} &= 
\frac
{\left(\frac{1}{\large{c}}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^2}
{
2
\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{{\large{c}}}\right)
}
\\[4pt]
&= \frac{b^2-c^2}{2bc}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;\bar{w} &= - w,\;\text{as required}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

This completes the proof.